# Am I pushing the limits of copyright law with this logo?

Tags: logo, copyright

I've produced this logo for a client. It's for a website with funny stories about working in retail.

[Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejR2K.jpg)

The logo is meant to parody the look of the following three retail companies in the UK:

https://www.tesco.com/

https://www.asda.com/

https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/

Just to clarify, I've used fonts that look similar rather than the exact fonts that the companies use. However, I'm concerned that the logo might be too similar to these companies (particularly Tesco) and could cause a problem.

I had heard that if you change a logo more than 7 times, it's no problem. But I have no idea if this is actually true.

Hoping to get some clarity from people that know more than I do - that would be you!

Thanks,
Ro

Comment: There's **no such thing** as "change by x amount and it's okay" That's a myth.

Comment: Thanks Zach. I did see that post. But I felt my question differed since the logo is text-based rather than an icon.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I did suspect that. I appreciate you confirming.

Comment: This is a poor design and legally complicated. Find another way to be creative.